# jQuery UI sortable: update order on database

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui

The script below returns a string with the order of IDs:

```
    $('#sortable').sortable({
        update: function(event, ui) {
            var newOrder = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
        $('input').attr("value", newOrder);     
        }
    });
```

For example: 88 , 24 , 32 , 10. In this case, the ID number 88 is the first order.

But how to pass this information to the database?

Comment: By using AJAX maybe?  Or alternatively: What have you tried?

Comment: I generally use AJAX. What have you tried?

Comment: Nothing yet. I would like to follow this script examples (http://www.karlrixon.co.uk/writing/update-multiple-rows-with-different-values-and-a-single-sql-query/). But I don't know how to move from where I am to the script.

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying the id in a column and you make that column sortable, then jQuery will sort the elements in the browser without any need to pass the info to the database.

Here is an example:  [jQuery-UI sortable table resizing column when first row is dragged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9402789/jquery-ui-sortable-table-resizing-column-when-first-row-is-dragged)

Comment: But I need record on a databse. The script works for the site administrator choose the order of photos.